# Non-uniform convergence of improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

**How do you show from the definition of uniform convergence that $I(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}dx$ does not converge uniformly for $a > 0$?**

Context: I was trying to evaluate $\lim_{a \to 0+}I(a)$ without using known closed form to learn more general technique.
If we could swap limit and integral, then the limit would be $0$ since $\lim_{a \to 0+}\sin(ax) = 0$. But I showed that the true limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ by changing variables: $u = ax$:

$$\lim_{a \to 0+}I(a) =  \lim_{a \to 0+}\int_0^\infty\frac{u\sin(u)}{u^2 + a^2}du= \int_0^\infty\lim_{a \to 0+}\frac{u\sin(u)}{u^2 + a^2}du=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u}du = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
In this form the integral is uniformly convergent for $a \geq 0$ (from Dirichlet test) so we can swap the limit and integral
That means $ \int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}dx$ is not uniformly convergent. The Dirichlet test conditions are not met but that doesn’t prove nonuniform convergence since that test is a sufficient but not necessary condition.
So how can you prove nonuniform convergence?  It also seems odd that changing variables results in uniform convergence.  Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the integral converged uniformly, we would have

$$\lim_{c \to \infty} \sup_{a >0} \left|\int_c^\infty \frac{x \sin ax}{x^2 +1 } \, dx \right|= 0$$

To show the convergence is not uniform, for any $c > 0$ take $a_c = 1/c >0$. Changing variables with $u = a_c x$ we get

$$\sup_{a >0} \left|\int_c^\infty \frac{x \sin ax}{x^2 +1 } \, dx \right|\geqslant \left|\int_c^\infty \frac{x \sin a_cx}{x^2 +1 } \, dx \right|= \left|\int_{a_c c}^\infty \frac{u \sin u}{u^2 + a_c^2} \, du\right| \\ = \left|\int_1^\infty \frac{u \sin u}{u^2 + 1/c^2} \, du\right|$$

But the integral on the RHS is uniformly convergent for all $c > 0$ by the Dirichlet test (as you pointed out).  Hence, we can swap the limit and integral to find

$$\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_1^\infty \frac{u \sin u}{u^2 + 1/c^2} \, du = \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin u }{u} \, du = 0.624713...$$

Thus,

$$ \lim_{c \to \infty} \sup_{a >0} \left|\int_c^\infty \frac{x \sin ax}{x^2 +1 } \, dx \right|> 0,$$

and the integral is not uniformly convergent for $a > 0$.